# How to load contract ABI in JavaScript

Tags: nearprotocol

Currently `near-js-sdk` and `create-near-app` show how to manually define your contract interface in JavaScript:

From `main.test.js` ( https://github.com/near/create-near-app/blob/master/templates/react/src/main.test.js#L5 ):

```js
  window.contract = await near.loadContract(nearConfig.contractName, {
    viewMethods: ['get_greeting'],
    changeMethods: [],
    sender: window.accountId
  })
```

However it is cumbersome to manually describe contract interface. How to make NEAR to load contract ABI information directly from the compiler files produced by `cargo build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't generate ABI for contracts yet since we want to support all languages that compile to Wasm, which would make it really hard to define language-agnostic ABI. However, we have experimented with some ideas: https://github.com/near/borsh/tree/master/borsh-rs/borsh-schema-derive-internal however, they are far from being integrated.

Comment: I suggest start with Rust and TypeScript and let all other languages derive their own bindings. Supporting all languages is really hard as you say and if you want to code in some niche language then you probably want to create your ABIs as well. My suggestion is that first do one language well and expand from there, as currently no language that satisfies basic needs of smart contract development.

Comment: Also, Solidity bindings seem to be a good inspiration. They work with almost any programming language and are not that complicate to implement. You might not be able to support all complex types of Rust, but at least there is a base starting point that is easy to implement.